# How to download a file and save it to the documents directory with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I am using the AFNetworking library. I can't figure out how to download a file and save it to the documents directory.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: You can even add a progress block:


    //Setup Upload block to return progress of file upload
        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
            NSLog(@"Download Percentage: %f %%", progress*100);
        }];

Comment: Be careful that the above code will download any response from the server to the output stream, so if the server responds with status code 404, the 404 page will be saved to the path specified. You must check on the success block for operation.response.statusCode.

Comment: Instead of manually checking the status code, just use `operation.hasAcceptableStatusCode`

Comment: `NSURLRequest` How to post or get one url?

Comment: how to download only in success block ? @leolobato can you advise please?

Comment: @leolobato No need, [AFNetworking takes care of this for you](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/137).

Comment: when i download video and click on back witho download completion. and again i click on video that time i get this error =>MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800  ... so plz help me

Comment: how to do this with POST with parameters?

Comment: how to call Get Type method with some header data and download a file

Answer (score 31):

I'm gonna bounce off @mattt's answer and post a version for AFNetworking 2.0 using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager GET:@"http://example.com/file/to/download" 
                               parameters:nil
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"successful download to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
op.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend doing it this way with the newer AFNetworking library

Comment: @swilliams [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] will create new manager object using default AFJSONResponseSerializer, do you want that? I think it 's better to create AFNoneResponseSerialize to let the file untouched

Comment: how can I get the download progress parameter in this ?

Comment: shshnk, look at my answer below

Comment: Is there a way to have the file cleaned up automatically if the download does not complete?

Comment: when i download video and click on back witho download completion. and again i click on video that time i get this error =>MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800  ... so plz help me

Answer (score 5):

I'm talking about **AFNetworking 2.0**

`[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]` creates manager object with default AFJSONResponseSerializer, and it performs content types restriction. Take a look at this

```
- (BOOL)validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
                    data:(NSData *)data
                   error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

So we need to create a none response serializer and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` as normal.

**Here is the AFNoneResponseSerializer**

```
@interface AFNoneResponseSerializer : AFHTTPResponseSerializer

+ (instancetype)serializer;

@end

@implementation AFNoneResponseSerializer

#pragma mark - Initialization
+ (instancetype)serializer
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - AFURLResponseSerializer
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error

{
    return data;
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFNoneResponseSerializer serializer];

[self.manager GET:@"https://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/xml/Books.xml"
           parameters:parameters
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        if (success) {
            success(responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];
```

so that we can get the whole file without any serialization

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) has example with section 'Creating a Download Task':

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

NB! Code work with iOS 7+ (tested with AFNetworking 2.5.1)

Comment: when i download video and click on back witho download completion. and again i click on video that time i get this error =>MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800  ... so plz help me

Answer (score 4):

From [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) docs.
Save to loaded file to your documents.
AFNetworking 3.0

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/octet-stream"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:url   parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (responseObject) {
        // your code here
    } else {
        // your code here
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];

[operation start];
```

//  manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject: @"application/octet-stream"]; can vary depending on what you expect

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is better to use `AFNetworking 2.0` way with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. With old way my file did download but for some reason didn't update in file system.

Appending to **swilliam's** answer, to show download progress, in `AFNetworking 2.0` you do similarly - just set download progress block after setting output stream.

```
__weak SettingsTableViewController *weakSelf = self;

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:newFilePath append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;

    NSString *progressMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %.2f %% \n %@ / %@", @"Downloading ...", progress * 100, [weakSelf fileSizeStringWithSize:totalBytesWritten], [weakSelf fileSizeStringWithSize:totalBytesExpectedToRead]];

    [SVProgressHUD showProgress:progress status:progressMessage];
}];
```

This is my method to create bytes string:

```
- (NSString *)fileSizeStringWithSize:(long long)size
{
    NSString *sizeString;
    CGFloat f;

    if (size < 1024) {
        sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", (int)size, @"bytes"];
    }
    else if ((size >= 1024)&&(size < (1024*1024))) {
        f = size / 1024.0f;
        sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f %@", f, @"Kb"];
    }
    else if (size >= (1024*1024)) {
        f = size / (1024.0f*1024.0f);
        sizeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f %@", f, @"Mb"];
    }

    return sizeString;
}
```

Comment: when i download video and click on back witho download completion. and again i click on video that time i get this error =>MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800  ... so plz help me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, with AFNetworking 2.5.0 and iOS7/8 I have found that that the extra step of opening the output stream is also needed to prevent the app from hanging (and eventually crashing from lack of memory).

```
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:dest
                                                          append:NO];
[operation.outputStream open];
[operation start];
```