# Download file multipart/form-data with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have 10 images, I uploaded to server using:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT"
                                                                         path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/AUTH_f4ea72a791db421fa2de4baa8579f691/%@/preImg", container]
                                                                   parameters:nil
                                                    constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
                                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                                                                    name:@"avatar"
                                                                                fileName:@"preIMG_0001.JPG"
                                                                                mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                                    }];
```

I get file include 10 images on server. How to download this file and split in to image, save in Document folder?

[How to download a file and save it to the documents directory with AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372661/how-to-download-a-file-and-save-it-to-the-documents-directory-with-afnetworking/8373637#8373637)

Thank in advanced.

Comment: Why do you need multipart to download? It is used in uploading images..

Comment: @Tung Why you append all the files and upload it to server? You can upload it seperately and download it seperately...

Comment: I think append all help me make progress bar easily and reduce number of url i must saved.

Comment: How to upload separately file to server use AFNetworking 1.3.3? Thank you