# Background (Asynchronous) programming in Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, asynchronous, background-process

I want something similar to C#'s `BackgroundWorker`.

I want to execute a block code of code (irrespective of what kind of code it is. It could be networking, I/O, complex math operations, whatever) in the background while I animate a `NSProgressIndicator`. Once the operation is complete, not only do I want to hide the progress indicator but I also want to receive result object(s) from the background code back to the main code.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this is better asked at progammers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @AyushISM, I think you required this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/uiprogresshud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do some reading about [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html), [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html), and [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Using these you can execute your "block" of code asynchronously and have it "schedule" an update of the progress indicator on the main thread every so often. You can set a completion block (callback) to execute when the operation is complete and it can call a function to be executed on the main thread.

[This article](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html) provides a nice overview of the options with small examples.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324193/929315) provides an example for defining and using a completion block.

Answer (score -1):

I think this library would be helpful - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

This library is a wrapper for Apple's API and has async tasks handled correctly. The example is shown here by Matt Thompson 
[How to download a file and save it to the documents directory with AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372661/how-to-download-a-file-and-save-it-to-the-documents-directory-with-afnetworking) 
how to use API for downloading a resource from a url in background. This is just one example but most of them work in a similar manner to perform task in background without blocking Main UI thread

Eg :-

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```