# Afnetworking download file only if status is okay

Tags: ios, download, afnetworking

I know a way to download file using Afnetworking from here.I am using that too.

[How to download a file and save it to the documents directory with AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372661/how-to-download-a-file-and-save-it-to-the-documents-directory-with-afnetworking)

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Problem is that it also download corrupted file or status not okay file.

Some people ask to check operation.hasAcceptableStatusCode.

How shall I do?

Comment: Did you checked the other answers? I know you used matt's answer (who's one of the best qualified to tell you how to use AFNetworking), but it's response is quite old, and AFNetworking has a lot changed since then.

Comment: yes I check. but they never mention how to download inside success block and how to avoid setting output stream.